# Cyclotomic cosets and quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and let $Q$ be the set of quadratic residues and $N$ the set of nonresidues. Assume $2 \in Q$. When I look a the cyclotomic cosets mod $p$, I get ${\{0}\}, {\{Q}\}, {\{N}\}.$ For example, for $p = 7,17,23$. Is this true in all cases?

What's the theory behind this?

Comment: The cyclotomic coset of $n \bmod p$ containing $i$ is $\{ i n^l \bmod p| l \ge 0\}$ ?

Comment: Yes? I still don’t understand why the above is true, though?

Comment: .. which $n,i,p$ are you considering

Comment: I’m looking at the cyclotomic cosets mod $p$, with $n=2$.

Comment: $Q$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ thus a cyclic group. What do you get for $\{ i n^l \bmod p| l \ge 0\}$ when $n$ a generator of $Q$ ? If $n \in Q$ then  $\{ n^l \bmod p| l \ge 0\} \subset Q$, what do you get when $n$ isn't a generator of $Q$ ?

Comment: So is $2$ a generator for $Q$ then?

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic with $p-1$ elements so it has only one subgroup with $(p-1)/2$ elements : $Q$